# Configuring multiple metadata.xml with its own entityid in SAML

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

We have a requirement of having multiple metadata.xml and its entity to enable SSO as we have multiple country sites running from a same instance and same code base.

What we did so far

> Customised the metadatageneratorfilter to set proper entity based on the request url (we have country code coming in the domain of url).

In Spring XML,

```
     <pre>
[bean id="metadata"  class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
        [constructor-arg>
            [list>
            [bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                     [constructor-arg>
                [bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">

                    [constructor-arg>
                        [value type="java.io.File">${sso.metadata.location:classpath:security/metadata_se.xml}[/value>
                    [/constructor-arg>
                    [property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                [/bean>
                [/constructor-arg>
                 [!-- added section starts -->
                    [constructor-arg>
                        [bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                                [property name="signingKey" value="ssoIDPCertr"/>
                        [/bean>
                    [/constructor-arg>
                    [!-- added section ends-->
                 [/bean>
                 [bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                     [constructor-arg>
                [bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">

                    [constructor-arg>
                        [value type="java.io.File">${sso.metadata.location:classpath:security/metadata_es.xml}[/value>
                    [/constructor-arg>
                    [property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                [/bean>
                [/constructor-arg>
                 [!-- added section starts -->
                    [constructor-arg>
                        [bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                                [property name="signingKey" value="ssoIDPCertr"/>
                        [/bean>
                    [/constructor-arg>
                    [!-- added section ends-->
                 [/bean>
                 [bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                     [constructor-arg>
                [bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">

                    [constructor-arg>
                        [value type="java.io.File">${sso.metadata.location:classpath:security/metadata_de.xml}[/value>
                    [/constructor-arg>
                    [property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                [/bean>
                [/constructor-arg>
                 [!-- added section starts -->
                    [constructor-arg>
                        [bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                                [property name="signingKey" value="ssoIDPCertr"/>
                        [/bean>
                    [/constructor-arg>
                    [!-- added section ends-->
                 [/bean>
            [/list>
        [/constructor-arg>
    [/bean>

</pre>


But this approach is not working as we dont have set providers against any unique values to identify the proper providers for countries.

our urls will be like 
<pre>
https://xy.brand.com

https://yy.brand.com
</pre>
```

Each site has separate metadata.xml.

we need to store metadata.xml with countryCode as identifiers and retrieve it based on request url before forming SAML request & response.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 0):

Is using a different entityID the only reason why you are separating your SP metadata xml files? If so, have you considered using [entity alias](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-entity-alias) ?

Comment: Please turn this into an answer. In its current shape it should be a comment instead. Please wait for your commenting privilege for working on unclear questions, until then look for quesitons you can answer without having to ask for clarification.